# Manipulating RGB color by copying channel value

Tags: image-processing, opencv, color

I have a picture and trying to swap the RGB channel into RRB, it's like I need to change all G pixels value into R. I did that by copying the R pixel value to G and store it into a new image file (Mat).
Here's my code :

```
ori.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0]; // B-->B
ori.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2]; // G-->R
ori.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = image.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2]; // R-->R
```

however the result is a little bit confusing me,

[image]

Could someone give me a brief explanation how is that the Red and Yellow pixels in the wall end up have the almost same result color (aquamarine) ? I checked the pixel value at some points and the value is almost the same.

What I expected was, if I copied R pixels --> G, part with original R values shouldn't be affected, right ? And because Yellow is a mixture of Red + Green, if I try to copy Red pixels into Green, shouldn't it be Red + Red then ?

**[UPDATE]**

I have checked sample color values (RGB) for Red wall and Yellow wall.

```
Red wall :              Yellow wall :
R --> 200 195 185       R --> 237 226 220
G -->   2   1   1       G --> 197 179 168
B -->   1   1   0       B -->   4  29  23

Copying the value R --> G :
Red wall :              Yellow wall :
R --> 200 195 185       R --> 237 226 220
G --> 200 195 185       G --> 237 226 220
B -->   1   1   0       B -->   4  29  23
```

will result in the Red wall and Yellow wall have almost the same color. But when I checked the result color, it's not aquamarine. Did I make wrong calculation ?

[image]

Comment: I don't see how your code and your description and code comments fit together. Your code says you assign R->R, B->G, B->B, assuming normal channel RGB ordering.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac In OpenCV default color space is BGR. Any picture will get loaded in BGR format by default. So the channel will always be [0]=B, [1]=G, [2]=R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the conversion part.
I converted the result image from BGR into RGB using this command :

```
cvtColor(image, image, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
```

Then I exported the result image into image file.

```
imwrite("image.png", image);
```

Turned out the export command will automatically convert the BGR color-space into the RGB color-space. This is why the color result is off because I did 2x conversion.
So, I don't need the conversion command.